# default values in avro schema not written to Java class

Tags: avro

I have a simple schema as follows:

```
{
 "name": "owner",
 "type": "record",
 "doc": "todo",
 "fields": [
   { "name": "version", "type": "int", "default": 1},
   { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "age", "type": "int" },
 ]
}
```

However when I use the avro-maven-plugin to generate a java object from this specificaion, it does not set the default value of version field to 1.

How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, It works fine as is.

I was looking at the generated Java class, and could not figure out where it was setting the default value to 1. But when I serialize it using json, I see the default value in the output. Also, the getter returns the default value as well.